# Data is ignored at ThenInclude() for nested List property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have more of a special case, and I am not sure what the reason is for what my issue is happening.

I have a class A with nested class B which also has a nested class C

```
public class A
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Name { get; set; }

        public List<B> Bs{ get; set; }
    }
```

---

```
public class B
   {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Name { get; set; }

        public List<C> Cs{ get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(A))]
        public int AId{ get; set; }
   }
```

---

```
public class C
   {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Name { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(B))]
        public int BId{ get; set; }
   }
```

---

Now the problem that I have is that the values of `class C` aren't included into `class B` when `class A` is called alongside with `Include()`, respectively `ThenInclude()` methods.

The way values are brought from DB Tables is using a normal SQL Query combined with LINQ.

```
var query = from queryResult in _dbSet.Include(a => a.B).ThenInclude(B => b.C)
            select new ResultModel()
            {
             Name = queryResult.Name
             B = queryResult.B
            }
```

The normal properties of B are being brought from db and mapped automatically to it, but the values for the nested List property aren't for some reason.

Do I need to make additional changes to select query in order for values of nested `class C` property be mapped into `class B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the question was not too confusing.

The problem I had was the property being ignored because of not being included in the select. So the solution would be to change from

```
var query = from queryResult in _dbSet.Include(a => a.B).ThenInclude(B => b.C)
            select new ResultModel()
            {
             Name = queryResult.Name
             B = queryResult.B
            }
```

to

```
var query = from queryResult in _dbSet.Include(a => a.B).ThenInclude(B => b.C)
            select new ResultModel()
            {
             Name = queryResult.Name
             B = queryResult.B.Select(x =>
                 new C {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Name = x.Name,
            }).ToList()
```

You can read more about this issue [here](https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/43541527/entity-framework-core-ignoring--include-----without--tolist-----indirectly).